# App fails right after start with IBM MobileFirst Platform with SecKeyGetBlockSize

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

We have a lot of users, but just a couple have this issue. The App crashes right after starting. Both Bitcode and ATS are disabled. What could be causing this issue? Thank you

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3          
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2017-05-16 18:05:01.2852 -0400
Launch Time:         2017-05-16 18:04:57.4399 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
SecKeyGetBlockSize + 0 (SecKey.c:696)
WLCertManager signData:privateKey:] + 276 (WLCertManager.m:525)
[WLDeviceAuthManager signDeviceAuth:entity:isPEnabled:] + 1168 (WLDeviceAuthManager.m:173)
[BaseProvisioningChallengeHandler onDeviceAuthDataReady:] + 172 (BaseProvisioningChallengeHandler.m:162)
[BaseDeviceAuthChallengeHandler getDeviceAuthDataAsync:] + 1308 (BaseDeviceAuthChallengeHandler.m:58)
[BaseProvisioningChallengeHandler handleChallenge:] + 1040 (BaseProvisioningChallengeHandler.m:138)
[WLRequest startHandleChallenges:httpRequest:]_block_invoke + 484 (WLRequest.m:606)
[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 136 (NSDictionary.m:680)
[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 180 (NSDictionary.m:692)
[WLRequest startHandleChallenges:httpRequest:] + 256 (WLRequest.m:598)
[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] + 604 (WLRequest.m:505)
[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] + 2020 (WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:396)
[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start]_block_invoke229 + 112 (WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:340)
[WLAFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke42 + 112 (WLAFHTTPRequestOperation.m:141)
dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:963)
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 444 (inline_internal.h:2417)
 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1793)
 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572 (CFRunLoop.c:3004)
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4089)
main + 200 (main.swift:12)
libdyld.dylib       0x000000018eeb559c start + 4
```

Full log here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1GqBSG2XUgZYmhJVGFRakFtWUU

It looks like it is happening when we are doing

```
private lazy var client: WLClient = WLClient.sharedInstance()
self.client.wlConnectWithDelegate(SomeDelegate)
```

MFP version is = 7.1-2016/07/11

Comment: Can you explain which app you are using and what is it doing? App seems to fail at first and then crash in error handling. The stack trace of code shows the MFP version 7.1 or below but knowing exact version of MFP will help.Even a wire trace of app execution will help further to debug.

Comment: MFP version is = 7.1-2016/07/11. May I send email to you? Here not enough space to attach trace. Thank you

Comment: Please upload to a file sharing service & share the link

Comment: I added more data in question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is caused by a null pointer reference. I have seen this before when wlConnectWithDelegate was being called more than once.
I would try to use Swift's `dispatch_once_t` singleton like this:

```
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
dispatch_once(&token) {
    //Make sure you register all challenge handlers then connect
    WLClient.sharedInstance().wlConnectWithDelegate(SomeDelegate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception looks like a keychain access error in MobileFirst SDK. MobileFirst does not support background mode in 7.1. Please make sure your app is not trying run MobileFirst connect APIs from background.Also make sure "KeyChain Sharing" is enabled in Targets->Capabilities.

Comment: 1. Is "KeyChain Sharing" mandatory for Xcode 7? We are still using Xcode 7. Documentation says it mandatory for Xcode 8 (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/16/mfp-support-for-ios10/) and all crashes happening in real devices. 2. Crashes happening right after start, around 4 seconds and logs told Apps in "Foreground".

Comment: Your log is showing iOS version as "iPhone OS 10.3.1 ". As you are running on device, keychain sharing does not matter.Similar error used to come for app in background or on locked phone-screen. For which we provided some fixes. At this point I can suggest you following. 1. Try with latest ifix for MFP 7.1. We did some keychain handling fixes begining of this year. 2. If #1 does not solve your issue, Open a PMR with IBM support and let us know if you can try with a debug build. So that we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed and published for MobileFirst 7.1